# Changing Editor for Unix INFO Command

Tags: editor, unix

Currently my "info" command uses Emacs as its default editor.

```
$ info printf
```

Is there a way to change it into Vi/Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something that understands TexInfo, which I don't believe Vi/Vim does.  You might just be stuck with emacs.  More info at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info_(Unix)).

Answer (score 2):

Your best hope that I can see is to run it with the --vi-keys command switch, which "uses vi-like and less-like key bindings". Unfortunately, I don't see anything else that can be of help to you.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the VISUAL and EDITOR environment variables to the full path of Vim.